# change value of a php variable on ajax content load

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I thought this would be really simple but obviously after a couple of days trial and no success I have to ask the people to help, looked everywhere.

right im basically creating a php template without much guidance on the foundation 4 framework with is a responsive framework. Now this framework is rather basic and so to add page transitions ive had to use jquery to do what i believe is an ajax call to take "content" from another page and display it on the template page index.html

for which I am currently using the following

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $('nav.top-bar > section.top-bar-section > ul.right > li > a').click(function()    {

    var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #content';
        $('#content').hide(1000,loadContent);
        $('#load').remove();
        $('#main_wrapper').append('<span id="load">LOADING...</span>');
        $('#load').fadeIn('fast');
                window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-0);
        function loadContent() {
        $('#content').load(toLoad,showNewContent);
        }
        function showNewContent() {
        $('#content').show(1000,hideLoader);
        }
        function hideLoader() {
        $('#load').fadeOut('fast');

        }
return false;

        }); 
  });
  </script>
```

NOW before i changed over to using ajax and jquery i was operating the menu "active" class and the page name with a simple variable set on each page in the first line listed as **$page='' and then the page name**

now that im loading the content with ajax even if i include this variable in the content of the new page it will not update in either the  or the menu title

im very sorry i dont write things correctly im new to this forum thing

thank you for the help in advance
:) I prefer someone to explain what i need to do and how to do it rather than just copy and pasting code as im a learner :)

Comment: Hi, what are you using $page for, and how? What is the intention with it? Do you maybe want to keep track of the last loaded content to open up the same on re-visit?

Comment: For the record, Foundation is a CSS framework with CSS styles to support responsive design (has no functional effect that I'm aware of).

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to load the page and parse the result in jQuery to get the new page’s `<title>` tag and set the requesting page’s `<title>` tag.

The only thing I’d ask is: why are  you doing this? Are you just wanting AJAX page navigation in your website instead of the traditional propagating navigation?

Comment: i think ive set up a php template and oringally i had ifelse conditions on the nav li items but now that i wated trasitions between the pages ive been told to use jquery . . only downside to that is when i put the `<?php echo $page;?>` in the <title></title> and the nav title and then put the page variable in the content its doesnt update it in either of these pages? that explanation any help

Comment: You can’t “update” a PHP variable when the page has been rendered. If you want to change something on a HTML page after it’s been rendered, then you need to a use a client-side technology such as JavaScript. The PHP script’s been processed, you can’t change variables.

Comment: and thats what im asking "how" can i change this i.e in the above listed function i tried to put a div around the variable and then change the content of that but didnt work

Comment: As I say: with a client-side technology like JS. You can’t change a PHP variable, it doesn’t exist any more once the script has been executed and the HTML rendered. You can’t change it. If you could, imagine how many websites could be compromised by changing configuration variables like database credentials. Forget PHP and variables; you’re left with the DOM to work with.

Answer (score 0):

I am only able to answer one part of your question due to extreme confusion, so:

First off, here's why your url changes:

```
window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-0);
```

You are modifying it with that line. That line, however, has an interesting little quirk:

```
attr('href').length-0
```

at the end. Why the -0? That would make no difference. I'd clean it up.

Outside of that, I'm incredibly confused with what you're asking so let me try rephrasing it and you can tell me what I'm missing.

You want to have a user click on a navigation link, and load that link's content via an AJAX call using jQuery, and then replace the content on the page with the newly loaded page, correct?

When you say "right on top main page i have variable $page = then the page name", what do you mean by "main page"? Do you mean it's a line of text in HTML? Part of a script that you haven't included here? Part of your PHP code?

And then you say "ive tried including the tag in a div that changes along with the above content"- what is "the tag"?

By reading this 4 or 5 times I could barely discern the above understanding of what you're trying to do.

Please make **heavy** edits to you question- it's incredibly hard to understand.

Lastly, why are you trying to replace the browser's functionality of a user clicking a link and loading content? That's what the browser is for. The browser also, conveniently, has a loading indicator in the url bar usually (or some form thereof), letting the user know the content is still loading.

Comment: have editted sorry :( that any better new to this forums thing

Comment: That's much more descriptive. here's a question for ya- are you getting anything back from "var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #content';"?

Comment: yes everything else is working the page disappears load-bar appears and then new content is loaded from a  page that contains nothing but the **<div id="content">Content Here</div>** and yes i am aware the foundation 4 is a css framework and yes it has no fancy page transitions or tbh many transitions of any kind hence why im going to this big effort to create them :(

Comment: Got it. I'm looking at the jquery docs and I think you're using load() wrong. New comment coming in a sec here...

Answer (score 0):

```
function loadContent() {
    $('#content').load(toLoad,showNewContent);
}
```

So first off, look at the jQuery doc for the load method:
http://api.jquery.com/load/

Your issue is that it is calling for three arguments, and you are passing two. If there are multiple arguments listed and you only want to pass SOME of them, you still need to supply a null value for the ones you want to "skip". Try changing your call to this:

```
function loadContent() {
    $('#content').load(toLoad, null, showNewContent);
}
```

You'll notice that I'm passing "null". If that doesn't work, pass an empty string, like this:

```
function loadContent() {
    $('#content').load(toLoad, "", showNewContent);
}
```

That second argument is data to be passed with the request. It's the THIRD argument that you list as your callback, which as far as I can tell is where you're making the mistake.